# How to set spacing between two SwiftUI List sections to a specific value?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to set the spacing between two sections to a specific value.
Here is my code:

```
List {
    Section() {
        Text("text 1")
        Text("text 2")
        }
    Section() {
        Text("text 3")
        Text("text 4")
    }
}
```

I tried setting `.environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight,5)` as below:

```
List {
    Section(header: Text("")) {
        Text("text 1")
        Text("text 2")
        }
    Section() {
        Text("text 3")
        Text("text 4")
    }
}.environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight,5)
```

But it doesn't work for small values, though it works for higher value.

Comment: The answer is simple, defaultMinListHeaderHeight sets the minimum, if you want to set your headers to a specific height, use a custom header view and set the height there with a frame and make sure that defaultMinListHeaderHeight is not larger than this value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this problem too and solve it by `listSectionSpacing`, like this:

```
List {
    Section() {
        Text("text 1")
        Text("text 2")
        }
    Section() {
        Text("text 3")
        Text("text 4")
    }
}
.listSectionSpacing(.custom(10)) // you can set any value to replace '10'
```